# Hyper-V connecting to a remote machine shows "The operation on computer 'x' failed

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, hyper-v, windows

I'm running Hyper-V manager using this command:

```
runas /user:DOMAIN\username "mmc \"C:\Program Files\Hyper-V\virtmgmt.msc\""
```

It is using a runas because the user I am logged into my machine as doesn't have permissions to access the remote hypervisors - I'm using a more privileged account to access the hypervisors.

When I connect to another server, it connects successfully. If I right click on the server in the list of servers, I can open Hyper-V settings etc. and it returns the correct settings, indicating that I am connected successfully.

However, where I would expect to see a list of virtual machines, instead there is a message saying "The operation on computer 'computername' failed". If I refresh the pane, the message changes to "No virtual machines were found on this server."

- If I run Hyper-V manager as a different higher privileged user, it works
- If I use remote desktop to log on to the hypervisor and connect to a different hypervisor from there, it works
- If I log on to my local machine with the higher privileged user and run Hyper-V, it works

I have tried deleting the entire user profile for the higher privileged user. The problem still occurs.

Both the local and remote machines are running Windows Server 2008 R2.

Any ideas for where to go next with this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. In my case no user on my machine can establish a successful connection and presents the symptoms you stated above. I am using a domain pc with a domain user (Windows 7 Pro). It was working fine at first and suddenly one day it started this behavior. Well, what I did was actually to install the Management Framework 4.0 and miraculously it worked! I suspect this started after some Windows Update and perhaps the Management Framework 4.0 setup either repaired some files or "synced" it with the new update. I will look into it to find exactly what happened, but till then this is my solution.